# Required permissions for Firehose Parquet Conversion

Tags: amazon-web-services

Kinesis Firehose delivery streams are capable of converting their input to parquet.
To achieve this, they need to be provided with an IAM role for accessing Glue.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/firehose/latest/APIReference/API_SchemaConfiguration.html

"RoleARN: The role that Kinesis Data Firehose can use to access AWS Glue. This role must be in the same account you use for Kinesis Data Firehose. Cross-account roles aren't allowed."

The documentation isn't clear on the requirements for this role.  Are there particular glue actions that need to be explicitly enabled for this role for the conversion to function?

Answer (score 1):

It expects access to the `glue:GetTableVersions` action for these resources:

```
          arn:aws:glue:{region}:{account_id}:catalog,
          arn:aws:glue:{region}:{account_id}:database/{database_name},
          arn:aws:glue:{region}:{account_id}:table/{database_name}/{table_name}
```

Comment: With string interpolation, something like
```
Resource: 
  - !Sub 'arn:aws:glue:${AWS::Region}:${AWS::AccountId}:catalog'
  - !Sub 'arn:aws:glue:${AWS::Region}:${AWS::AccountId}:database/${utcGlueDatabaseName}'
  - !Sub 'arn:aws:glue:${AWS::Region}:${AWS::AccountId}:table/${GlueDatabaseResourceName}/${GlueTableResourceName}'
```

Answer (score 1):

The policy required is documented here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/firehose/latest/dev/controlling-access.html#using-iam-glue

It says you need the following policy:

```
{
  "Effect": "Allow",
  "Action": [
    "glue:GetTable",
    "glue:GetTableVersion",
    "glue:GetTableVersions"
  ],
  "Resource": "table-arn"
}
```